# unix select() call: how to combine fd_sets?

Tags: c, unix, network-programming

I am writing an application in C for linux, which uses 2 separate third-party libraries. Both libraries are asynchronous and use select(). They also provide an API which returns the file descriptors they wait on. My intention is to pass these into my own select() and then return control back to whichever library when their own fd values are set.

I think I've got most of it written, but I have trouble at the point where the select() parameters are concerned: Both libraries do not give individual file descriptors, but pointers to their read and write fd_sets. I need to combine the returned fd_sets from these libraries into one fd_set for read, one fd_set for write, etc.

Any suggestions on how I can combine 2 fd_sets into one resulting fd_set?

**Addendum** Sorry! I should have been clearer.. these libraries only return the fd_sets... I don't know the number of FDs in each set so that I can do a for loop and set each FD individually.. is there a simple way of determining this given just an fd_set?

Comment: *I am writing an application in C for linux, which uses 2 separate third-party libraries.* should be *I am writing an application in C for Linux which uses two third-party libraries.*

Comment: Are you sure that this strategy will work? Typically such libraries implement their own event loop and expect you to set up callbacks and transfer control to them exclusively. The good ones will allow you to add file descriptors of your own to their select lists. In a single-threaded program you can't easily have 2 exclusive control event loops never mind 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up your own `fd_set` by looping over all possible file descriptors that each library could possibly have open and in each of their returned sets and set your's accordingly. It's a bit brute-force but the select interface is unfortunately quite primitive. For example

```
fd_set *lib1_read_fds, *lib2_read_fds;
int fd;
fdset my_fd_set;
FD_CLR(&my_fd_set);
for (fd = 0; fd < FD_SETSIZE; fd++) {
    if (FD_ISSET(fd, lib1_read_fds) || FD_ISSET(fd, lib2_read_fds)) {
        FD_SET(fd, &my_fd_set);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use FD_ZERO, not FD_CLR to zero the result set.

Comment: Since `select()` needs the number of the highest fd+1 (nfds), the libraries have to provide nfds and you can replace FD_SETSIZE with nfds and reducing the iterations by a lot. You could just check the fds in the shorter one (lower nfds) and copy them to the other fdset.

Answer (score 5):

C code which doesn't depend on the implementation of `fd_set`:

```
void Fdset_Add(fd_set *Out, fd_set const *In, int InNfds)
{
    for(i = 0; i < InNfds; i++)
    {
        if(i < InNfds && FD_ISSET(i, In))
            FD_SET(i, Out);
    }
}

int Fdset_Merge(fd_set *Out, fd_set const *In1, int NFds1, fd_set const *In2, int NFds2)
{
    FD_ZERO(Out);
    Fdset_Add(Out, In1, Nfds1);
    Fdset_Add(Out, In2, Nfds2);
    return Nfds1 > Nfds2 ? Nfds1 : Nfds2;
}

int Fdset_Filter(fd_set const *Result, int ResultNfds, fd_set *ToFilter, int NfdsToFilter)
{
    int i;
    int Retval;

    Retval = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < ResultNfds; i++)
    {
        if(i < NfdsToFilter && FD_ISSET(i, ToFilter))
        {
            if(! FD_ISSET(i, Result))
                FD_CLR(i, ToFilter);
            else
                Retval++;
        }
    }
    return Retval;
}

void Fdset_Split(fd_set const *Result, int ResultNfds, fd_set *In1, int Nfds1, int *Count1, fd_set *In2, int Nfds2, int *Count2)
{
     *Count1 = Fdset_Filter(Result, ResultNfds, In1, Nfds1);
     *Count2 = Fdset_Filter(Result, ResultNfds, In1, Nfds2);
}
```

Comment: in FDSet_Merge() you only loop up to the minimum of NFds1 and NFds2.  You need to loop up to the maximum of the two

Comment: Shouldn't that be "const fd_set *In", and so on?

Comment: @unwind - I try to put the `const` to the right of the type, as it will always qualify the type directly to its left.  Maintaining this style reinforces that understanding, so that if I encounter something like `int * const * Something;`, it's easier to remember which part is being marked read-only.

Answer (score 1):

Without relying on the internal implementation of `fd_set`, the best you can do is a simple pair of loops

```
fd_set combine_sets(fd_set* p_set1, int n1, fd_set* p_set2, int n2)
{
   fd_set combined;
   int i;

   FD_ZERO(combined);

   for (i = 0; i < n1; ++i) {
     if (FD_ISSET(i, p_set1)) {
       FD_SET(i, &combined);
     }
   }

   for (i = 0; i < n2; ++i) {
     if (FD_ISSET(i, p_set2)) {
       FD_SET(i, &combined);
     }
   }

   return combined;
}
```

Where the `n` parameters are the largest descriptor number potentially in the corresponding set, plus one (i.e. the `nfds` argument that you would pass to `select` if you were using just that set).

**Edit:** Changed to take pointers as arguments, since that's what you said you are getting from your libraries.

Comment: Returning an fd_set seems like a really bad idea. It's been a while since I read POSIX but it may even allow fd_set to be an array type, in which case this code would fail. Better to pass a pointer to an fd_set and let the function write into that...

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through one set and check each fd up to FD_SETSIZE with FD_ISSET() and if it is set, set the fd in the other set using FD_SET()

Answer (score 0):

The fd_set is actually a bitmap. Maybe you can combine them using binary or.

```
typedef long int __fd_mask;

typedef struct
{
    __fd_mask __fds_bits[__FD_SETSIZE / __NFDBITS];
} fd_set;
```

Comment: One might need to take special care about the size of the fd_set: it can be also dynamically allocated. Accessing bytes past the `(nfds+7)/8` (where `nfds` is the first select()'s argument) should be avoided. Unless of course one can confirm that the libraries are actually using the proper fd_set from sys/select.h.

Comment: Except in the most performance-intensive applications, I would recommend strongly against this approach. Looking inside opaque data structures and writing code that depends on their implementation is a very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that portably, however if you rewrite your code to use `poll()` you can merge the sets it uses since they are just arrays of portably `struct`s