# Handle many Gpio Interruptions C++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux, gpio

I have an interruptions problem. I am working in an application which has to handle many buttons by interruptions. I am using this program to handle one:

```
int main(){
 gpio_export(gpio);
 gpio_set_dir(gpio, 0);
 gpio_set_edge(gpio, "falling");
 gpio_fd = gpio_fd_open(gpio);
timeout = POLL_TIMEOUT;


while (1) {
    memset((void*)fdset, 0, sizeof(fdset));

    fdset[0].fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    fdset[0].events = POLLIN;

    fdset[1].fd = gpio_fd;
    fdset[1].events = POLLPRI;

    rc = poll(fdset, nfds, timeout);


    if (rc < 0) {
        printf("\npoll() failed!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (rc == 0) {
        printf(".");
    }

    if (fdset[1].revents & POLLPRI) {
        len = read(fdset[1].fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
        printf("\npoll() GPIO %d interrupt occurred\n", gpio);
    }


    if (fdset[0].revents & POLLIN) {
        (void)read(fdset[0].fd, buf, 1);
        printf("POLLIN");
        //printf("\npoll() stdin read 0x%2.2X\n", (unsigned int) buf[0]);
    }


    fflush(stdout);
}

gpio_fd_close(gpio_fd);
gpio_fd_close(gpio_fd2);
return 0;
```

}

It is working perfectly, my problem is that what I want to do is handle more interruptions so what I tried is this:

```
while (1) {
    memset((void*)fdset, 0, sizeof(fdset));

    fdset[0].fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    fdset[0].events = POLLIN;

    fdset[1].fd = gpio_fd;
    fdset[1].events = POLLPRI;

    rc = poll(fdset, nfds, timeout);

    memset((void*)fdset2, 0, sizeof(fdset2));

    fdset2[0].fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    fdset2[0].events = POLLIN;

    fdset2[1].fd = gpio_fd2;
    fdset2[1].events = POLLPRI;

    rc2 = poll(fdset2, nfds, timeout);

    if (rc < 0 || rc2 < 0) {
        printf("\npoll() failed!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (rc == 0 || rc2==0) {
        printf(".");
    }

    if (fdset[1].revents & POLLPRI) {
        len = read(fdset[1].fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
        printf("\npoll() GPIO %d interrupt occurred\n", gpio);
    }
    if (fdset2[1].revents & POLLPRI) {
        len = read(fdset2[1].fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
        printf("\npoll() GPIO %d interrupt occurred\n", gpio2);
    }

    if (fdset[0].revents & POLLIN) {
        (void)read(fdset[0].fd, buf, 1);
        printf("POLLIN");
        //printf("\npoll() stdin read 0x%2.2X\n", (unsigned int) buf[0]);
    }

    if (fdset2[0].revents & POLLIN) {
        (void)read(fdset2[0].fd, buf, 1);
        printf("POLLIN");
                //printf("\npoll() stdin read 0x%2.2X\n", (unsigned int) buf[0]);
    }

    fflush(stdout);
}

gpio_fd_close(gpio_fd);
gpio_fd_close(gpio_fd2);
return 0;
```

}

Basically I tried to handle two interruptions in the same program, but when I push any button nothing happend. What can I do that? shall I use threads?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to merge fdset-s  before you call poll. Basically the program waits at first poll call instead of waiting on first and second in parralel. So you can use threads or call one poll for all fdset-s and once.

Comment: Hi Lukasz thank you for your answer, but how can I do one poll for all fdset-s??  you mean this function right?   rc = poll(fdset, nfds, timeout);  shall I use just one fdset?? How can I call poll function for every fdset? I am using threads for other actions so I prefer handle this one in other way. Thank you again

Comment: You have to write a simple helper function to join to fdset-s into one and then call poll with the new one.

Comment: can I see some example?? Is the first time I handle interruptions and I do not have too much Idea. a simple example could be perfect thank you

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195515/unix-select-call-how-to-combine-fd-sets

Comment: Hi Lukasz I had a look the link but I am using pollfd struct intead of fdset then I do not if I can use that. What can I do??

Comment: I define that struct pollfd fdset[2];